# Why does SLRequest to get Twitter followers crash on iOS 6.1 but not 7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, twitter, ios6

I tried to load a list of the user's Twitter followers. It loads fine on iOS 7.1, but crashes on iOS 6.1. The line that crashes is `performRequestWithHandler:` and the error is *-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcb4d580*. What is the cause of the problem?

```
SLRequest* request = [SLRequest
    requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
    requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET
    URL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:
        @"%@followers/list.json",
        API_BASE_URL
    ]]
    parameters:@{
        @"user_id": @(self.context.userId.integerValue),
        @"count": @(128),
        @"skip_status": @"true"
    }
];
request.account = self.context.account;
[request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
    // code that is irrelevant to crash
}];
```

These are how the above variables are defined:

- API_BASE_URL is a static NSString @"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/"
- self.context.userId is an NSString of a number.
- self.context.account is the ACAccount of the logged in user.

Comment: Please point out the exact line of code causing the crash.

Comment: @rmaddy : I did. It is the `performRequestWithHandler:` line.

Comment: OK, it really is on that line and not in the handler. My guess is that the problem is caused by the `count` parameter being an `NSNumber` instead of an `NSString`. Change `@(128)` to `@"128"`. Also make the `user_id` a string instead of a number.

Comment: @rmaddy . It is the request line and not the handler because it crashes before it can handle it. You are right about the NSNumber. iOS 6's internal implementation expects all the parameters to be NSString. iOS 7 can intelligently convert NSNumber to strings. You can submit your answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the error message it seems under iOS 6 you must be sure all request parameters are strings. Change your code for the parameters to something like:

```
parameters:@{
    @"user_id": self.context.userId,
    @"count": @"128",
    @"skip_status": @"true"
}
```